# How does the Compiler treat Selection Statement Variations

Tags: java, compiler-construction, jvm, javac, bytecode

All three methods below are functionally identical - however they all have what I've perceived to be stylistical differences. When these are compiled, does the compiler treat them differently? (I lack the know-how to examine and understand the decompiled bytecode)

```
// Method 1
private boolean isAcceptableRange(final int a, final int b) {       
    if ((Math.abs(a - b)) <= range) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Method 2
private boolean isAcceptableRange(final int a, final int b) {       
    if ((Math.abs(a - b)) <= range) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Method 3
private boolean isAcceptableRange(final int a, final int b) {
    if ((Math.abs(a - b)) <= range)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

My initial thoughts are #1 will be unique due to the extra `else` clause, where #2 and #3 will end up being identical. This would mean when optimizing for disk/rom space efficiency and possibly instruction efficiency (thinking embedded), go with option #2 or #3.

Or does the compiler know the end result and "optimize" it away?

Comment: You can view the bytecode with `javap -c`.

Comment: I would still recommend using `return (Math.abs(a - b)) <= range;` instead of any of your three variants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't looked at the bytecode either.  But based on my general knowledge about compiler technology:  `if (condition) {then-part} else {else-part}` results in code that looks basically like:

```
if (!condition) branch to Label_1;
perform then-part;
branch to Label_2;
Label_1:
perform else-part;
Label_2:
```

In your example #1, the "then-part" is a `return` statement.  And the code for a `return` statement would either be a `return` instruction, or a `branch` to some point at the end of the subroutine code where it does cleanup (including any `finally` that's in effect) and then returns.  And a decent compiler would not generate a branch (or any other code) following another unconditional branch or a `return` instruction, since that code could never be executed.  So example #1 would end up looking like

```
if (!condition) branch to Label_1;
set return value to "true";
return or branch to cleanup code;
Label_1:
set return value to "false";
return or branch to cleanup code;
```

And this would be the exact same code generated by examples #2 or #3.

So the answer to your question is: no, the compiler would not treat any of your examples differently, unless it is a really poor compiler.

Answer (score 4):

> Or does the compiler know the end result and "optimize" it away?

Yes, it does. Let's see the produced bytecode:

```
javap -c -private MyClass.class
```

- `javap`: is a tool that (among other things) lets you see the bytecode of java classes, it comes with the JDK.
- `-c`: disassembles the code to bytecode
- `-private`: shows the private members and methods in your class.
- `MyClass.class`: the compiled class

---

```
private boolean isAcceptableRange1(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1       
       1: iload_2       
       2: isub          
       3: invokestatic  #1                  // Method java/lang/Math.abs:(I)I
       6: aload_0       
       7: getfield      #2                  // Field range:I
      10: if_icmpgt     15
      13: iconst_1      
      14: ireturn       
      15: iconst_0      
      16: ireturn       

  private boolean isAcceptableRange2(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1       
       1: iload_2       
       2: isub          
       3: invokestatic  #1                  // Method java/lang/Math.abs:(I)I
       6: aload_0       
       7: getfield      #2                  // Field range:I
      10: if_icmpgt     15
      13: iconst_1      
      14: ireturn       
      15: iconst_0      
      16: ireturn       

  private boolean isAcceptableRange3(int, int);
    Code:
       0: iload_1       
       1: iload_2       
       2: isub          
       3: invokestatic  #1                  // Method java/lang/Math.abs:(I)I
       6: aload_0       
       7: getfield      #2                  // Field range:I
      10: if_icmpgt     15
      13: iconst_1      
      14: ireturn       
      15: iconst_0      
      16: ireturn
```

I called the methods `isAcceptableRange1`, `isAcceptableRange2`, `isAcceptableRange3`. As you can see, all methods have the exact same bytecode.